# Using Regex to 'Clean Up' a List of Names

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am using Regex to clean up a list of names so that they are normal. Let's say this list was...

```
000000AAAAAARob Alsod     ## Notice multiple 0's and A's?
AAAPerson Person          ## Here, too
Jeff the awesome Guy      ## Four words...
Jenna DEeath              ## A name like this can exist.
GEOFFERY EVERDEEN         ## All caps
shy guy                   ## All lowercase
Theone Normalperson       ## Example name. This one is fine.
  Guywith Whitespace      ## Trailing or leading whitespace is a nono.
```

So, as you can see, people don't format their names correctly, so I need a program to highlight all the unwanted stuff. This includes:

- Numbers at the *start* of the name.
- *Any* uppercase without lowercase after. i.e. AAAAAAAJosh
- Anything that is *all* uppercase.
- Anything that doesn't *start* with uppercase. i.e. josh
- Trailing and leading whitespace.

I think that is all I need to filter out. The ending product should look something like this:

```
Rob Alsod              ## No more 0's and A's.
Person Person          ## No more leading A's (or other letters).
Jeff Guy               ## No lowercase words in his name.
Jenna DEeath           ## HASN'T removed the D in the middle.
                       ## Name removed as it was all uppercase.
                       ## Name removed as it was all lowercase.
Theone Normalperson    ## Nothing changed.
Guywith Whitespace     ## Removed whitespace.
```

EDIT: Sorry about that. Here is my current code:

```
# Enter your code for "Name Cleaning" here.
import re
namenum = []
num = 0
for sen in open('file.txt'):
  namenum += [sen.split(',')]
  namenum[num][0] = re.sub(r'\s[a-z]+', '', namenum[num][0])
  namenum[num][0] = re.sub(r'^([0-9]*)', '', namenum[num][0])
  namenum[num][0] = re.sub(r'^[A-Z]*?\s[A-Z]*?$', '', namenum[num][0])
  namenum[num][0] = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z ][A-Z]*(?=[A-Z])', '', namenum[num][0])
  namenum[num][0] = re.sub(r'\b[a-z]+\b', '', namenum[num][0])
  namenum[num][0] = re.sub(r'^\s*', '', namenum[num][0])
  namenum[num][0] = re.sub(r'\s*$', '', namenum[num][0])  
  if namenum[num][0] == '':
    namenum[num][0] = 'Invalid Name'
  num += 1
for i in range(len(namenum)):
  namenum[i][1] = int(namenum[i][1].strip())
namenum = sorted(namenum, key=lambda item: (-item[1], item[0]))
for i in range(0, len(namenum)):
  print(namenum[i][0]+','+str(namenum[i][1]))
```

It does half the job, but it misses out on some stuff for some reason.

Here is the output:

```
AAAAAARob Alsod
AAAPerson Person
Guywith Whitespace
Invalid Name
Invalid Name
Jeff Guy
Jenna DEeath
Theone Normalperson
```

I also tried inputting a name like `harry hamilton` and it gave back `harry`, which it should have removed.

Comment: You actually have to *try* something. Where's your code so far? We are not a free code factory. -1, closevoted

Comment: Sorry. I have edited OP.

Comment: What stuff does it miss out on?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would you need to do this? Names are complicated.

Comment: I am creating a database. It contains names of people in our system. Unfortunately, the names are manually entered, which causes some people to joke about and write `Robert le awesome Alsod` instead of their normal name. By the way, @Michelle, it is edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex removes all your invalid examples. None of your examples requires the for loop which filters banned words, but I think you will need it.

Although this code removes all invalid names from a list it should be easy to modify it to request a new input from the user. Also it doesn't let you know why a name is invalid, but you could just display all the rules.

```
from re import match

def rules(name):
    for badWord in bannedWords:
        if name.lower().find(badWord) >= 0:
            return False        
    return match(r'^([A-Z][a-z]+(?:[A-Z]?[a-z]+)* ?){1,}$', name)

bannedWords = ('really', 'awesome')
input = ['000000AAAAAARob Alsod', 'AAAPerson Person', 'Jeff the awesome Guy', 'Jenna DEeath', 'GEOFFERY EVERDEEN', 'shy guy', 'Theone Normalperson', '  Guywith Whitespace', 'Someone Middlename MacIntyre', '', 'Jack Really Awesome']
results = filter(rules, input)
print results
```

Produces the result:

```
['Theone Normalperson', 'Someone Middlename MacIntyre']
```

Without the for loop:

```
from re import match

def rules(name):     
    return match(r'^([A-Z][a-z]+(?:[A-Z]?[a-z]+)* ?){1,}$', name)

input = ['000000AAAAAARob Alsod', 'AAAPerson Person', 'Jeff the awesome Guy', 'Jenna DEeath', 'GEOFFERY EVERDEEN', 'shy guy', 'Theone Normalperson', '  Guywith Whitespace', 'Someone Middlename MacIntyre', '', 'Jack Really Awesome']
results = filter(rules, input)
print results
```

Produces the result:

```
['Theone Normalperson', 'Someone Middlename MacIntyre', 'Jack Really Awesome']
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This should work.